# LINQPad: get plain SQL query from hardcoded objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I use free version of LinqPAD.

I have only .cs files with code. I can't run and debug it. I don't have Database.
(And I'm not C# programmer.)

I need to convert Linq queries to raw SQL(MsSql) query. I want to see plain SQL query.

So I open LinqPAD and write hardcoded objects/classes which represent three tables from DB.

I switch to "C# Program".

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public int UserSecondId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}

class Contacts
{
    public int OrganizationId { get;set; }
    public int UserId { get;set; }
    public char IsPrimary { get;set; }
}

class Organizations
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int SecondId { get;set; }
}

class Users
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public char IsActive { get;set; }
    public int SecondId { get;set; }
}

void Main()
{

    List<Contacts> Contacts = new List<Contacts>();
    Contacts.Add(new Contacts { OrganizationId = 1, UserId = 1, IsPrimary = 'Y' });
    Contacts.Add(new Contacts { OrganizationId = 2, UserId = 1, IsPrimary = 'Y' });

    List<Organizations> Organizations = new List<Organizations>();
    Organizations.Add(new Organizations { Id = 1, SecondId = 1 });
    Organizations.Add(new Organizations { Id = 2, SecondId = 2 });

    List<Users> Users = new List<Users>();
    Users.Add(new Users { Id = 1, SecondId = 1, IsActive = 'Y' });
    Users.Add(new Users { Id = 2, SecondId = 1, IsActive = 'Y' });

    int[] orgSecondIdList = { 1, 2 };

    var query =
        from contacts in Contacts
        from orgs in Organizations.Where(o => o.Id == contacts.OrganizationId)
        from users in Users.Where(o => o.Id == contacts.UserId)
        where contacts.IsPrimary == 'Y' && users.IsActive == 'Y' &&
        orgSecondIdList.Contains(orgs.SecondId)
        select new ContactModel
        {
            OrganizationId = contacts.OrganizationId,
            UserId = contacts.UserId,
            UserSecondId = users.SecondId
        };

    query.Dump();
```

}

I press run.
LinqPAD shows me table in Vizualizer. But SQL tab is empty.

What is wrong? Can I get raw SQL query?
Like `SELECT ... FROM ...`

Comment: Your code has no features that are related to/depend on SQL or a database at all, its a load of basic classes & a linq query.  With nothing in a runnable state you cannot execute & capture the generated SQL from the actual code.

Comment: Is it possible to convert Linq query to SQL? I can see correct result in table. And I don't understand why I can't see SQL which showed me this table? Is there tools to just convert Linq into plain SQL without real data and databases? (Because I don't see difficultes for it)

Comment: You're not seeing any SQL because you are not executing any SQL!  The Linq2Sql code in LinqPad convert your linq code to SQL, but since you aren't using it there's nothing to convert!

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there possibility to convert Linq code (a lot of code) to SQL without database and debugging? I don't see any difficultes for it, because we need to convert from one conventional syntax to another conventional syntax (without checking of real data). For example `from contacts in Contacts` is `SELECT ... FROM Contacts AS contacts`

Comment: The SQL generated by LINQ to SQL or EF depends heavily on the database provider being used and can be different - some providers don't use SQL at all. You could, for example, create simple local SQLite database with the IQ driver and then view the generated SQLite SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You'll require the backing of a SQL database if your wish is to utilise LinqPads functionality to convert Linq queries into SQL for you. LinqPad also offers a number of drivers allowing you to use a number of data sources (e.g. SQLite) which require less overhead than say MSSQL. Without a SQL database LinqPad can't help you.

If you want to pursue using LinqPads functionality without a database you'll need to use the classes you listed above to make your database schema. If the code was in a C# project using Visual Studio, Entity Framework can use code first to generate the DB schema for you based on those classes.